# Aligning two different-sized divs vertically such that the smaller one is centered

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/RaP2D/5/

I've been trying for a while to figure out how to make 'Small Text' vertically-align with 'Large Text'. I did some reading, tried various examples with wrapping the content, using display:table, etc.

I would prefer not to float the elements, but if that is the easiest way then OK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the rule `vertical-align:middle;` to `#OrdersEditTitle` seems to do it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RaP2D/6/)**

```
#OrdersEditTitle {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #2E6E9E;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Gah. I applied vertical-align: middle to a wrapper div and thought that would be sufficient. Okay, thank you. Sorry for the trivial question.

Comment: That didn't work for you because vertical-align only applies to inline level elements.

Answer (score 0):

Either do what j08691 said, or set the position to relative and the top to `-5px`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaP2D/7/)

```
#FiltersHaveChangedHighlight {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    position:relative;
    top:-5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
​
```