# Align two different sized divs along the middle

Tags: html, css

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644479/aligning-two-different-sized-divs-vertically-such-that-the-smaller-one-is-center) and the solution *seems* to work because the divs aren't so different in sizes.

My question is how can we effectively align two divs of arbitrary sizes along the middle of the parent container?

The HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="big">
    </div>
    <div id="small">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#container { }
#big {width:100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block;border:1px solid black; vertical-align:middle; }
#small {width:50px; height: 50px; display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;}
```

See [on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzjEk/3/)

**EDIT**
What I really want is something like this

[image: Aligned Like this]

Comment: align vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Not getting what exactly you want. post the desired output screenshot

Comment: My bad. I added a picture to explain what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to `#small`

```
#small {
width:50px; 
height: 50px; 
display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid red; 
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hzjEk/6/)**

Comment: I swear I tried this and it did not work then!! Maybe I need to take a walk. Thanks

Comment: @RedBaron :) ya sometimes it happens

Answer (score 2):

Its enough to do this

```
#container { text-align: center; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzjEk/4/)

---

**Edit**
As you want now, you need to

```
#small { vertical-align:middle; }
```

[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hzjEk/8/)

Comment: The red and black boxes need to be aligned. See the picture I added, if it helps